# Google Api 64bit Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4, google-api

I want to implement in my Mac application the google API for uploading file on Gdocs, sadly I discovered that Google api for Objective-C are still in 32bit while my app is in 64bit with the new ARC support.

So before converting my app to 32bit I tried to build the google api in 64bit, I downloaded the .diff patch found here:
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/issues/detail?id=30
and applied it.

Then I tried to rebuild the Google api in 64bit and it succeded (before there  were errors), so I copied the Gdata framework in my project and I was able to build it without errors.

BUT, when I click play this is the error I retrieve:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/GData.framework/Versions/A/GData
Referenced from: /Users/Xeo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GdocSync-fpcfhxbalzflkxdigudsndijtiol/Build/Products/Debug/GdocSync.app/Contents/MacOS/GdocSync
Reason: image not found
```

The framework is linked, I set it in the frameworks to link, soI don't really know how to do this, I would like to waste another bit of time before converting the app to 32bit!

EDIT: i was able to build it under xcode 4 with arc support only adding the sources into my app and building directly from there as explained in the google wiki.
No luck with the framework!

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the derived data from your app in the Xcode 4 organizer, give the target a good scrubbing and build again.